How to read the output of a slot-type photomicrosensor with a MCU?
I am trying to use an optocoupler as an edge sensor (to restrict motion). I am using these ones:  https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001921249243.html
Or same diagram here: https://assets.omron.eu/downloads/latest/datasheet/en/ee-sx47_67_slot-type_photomicrosensor_(non-modulated)_datasheet_en.pdf?v=4
This is the I/O diagram:

Recently I realized I need sensor with a wider gap (10mm instead of 5mm), but those are powered from 12V, not 5V.
My main question is Could I read the output from those 12V-powered sensors with the usual I/O pins of MCU (for example, hosted on an Arduino board)? I understand that the output is open-collector and using the pull-up would solve the problem at first sight:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
BUT, I am wondering about that output Zener: does it matter for my setup ? And, moreover, I tried to measure its Zener voltage by measuring the Load voltage (I just used the 1.7k resistor as a load and I used the diagram from the spec). But that voltage was always the same as the power supply voltage (I tried the range from 5 to 13V). Did I do something wrong to measure that Zener voltage ?

@Drew - Thanks for trying to help. However that comment effectively answers the question and we're getting flags to highlight that. Answering is not an allowed use of comments - see here & here. Also see here (this person was SE staff when they posted this, and it is referenced from an FAQ answer, so consider it "official"). Therefore please will you consider moving your comment into an answer? TY

Sure I'll move, it. But I think using the comments is appropriate when you know the answer to the question, but you don't have the time to give a full answer with citations and all that. Giving a terse answer can hurt more than it helps, as it changes the question to "answered" in the list.

That's how NPN sensors are intended to be used. You shouldn't have any issues.
The Zener diode should not have any effect, either. From the look of it, those are actually TVS diodes.

Thank you for your answer ! Let me ask one more question then :) I will investigate it anyway, but in order to have everything in one place: is it safe to connect the power supply's GND (-) and the Arduino's one ?

Yes, they must be connected for this to work.
